# Why /usr and /home size is very small even tough I gave /home and / (root) enaugh size?

Tags: linux, partition, disk-usage, disk, size

My concern is about /usr and home size as you see.

Home:
[image]

Root:
[image]

My concern is about /usr and home size as you see.

It seems that they have really small space, but when I was installing ubuntu I gave enough size for / (root that contains /usr) and also for home. the df -h shows :

- Root : /dev/nvme0n1p5 32G 6.9G 23G 24% /
- Home : /dev/nvme0n1p8 142G 311M 135G 1% /home

[image]

So where is the problem? why am I seeing nearly full strorage in both? and in case I reinstall ubuntu what should I do?

Comment: Can you add to the question the figures that you think show "nearly full storage" ?  You may be misreading the column headings or the scaling factors (KB, MB, GB) in the `df -h` output.   /home is 99% empty.   / (root) is 76% empty.   Ignore the 100% usage on the loop-back mounts -- they don't count.

Comment: Yes exactly, the df -h  outputs is good but why disk usage analyzer is showing them in red? (the two first mages)

Comment: I can never figure what those graphic things actually mean, and they are never properly documented. I trust the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think that too, I should never rely on something else other than trusted commands. Because I think the software has other interpretations for memory use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screens you’re looking at don’t show the proportion of disk space used compared to the disk space available; they only show the share of disk space used.

Your `/home` volume is 142GiB in size, out of which 311MiB are used; your home directory uses 260.3MB of that. The “Home folder” screenshot shows a full bar because the only directory being shown accounts for all the used disk space in the folders being displayed.

Likewise, your `/` volume is 32GiB in size, but only 6.9GiB is in use. `/` accounts for all of that, so it gets a full bar in the second screenshot; `/usr` accounts for most of that, so it gets a red bar itself, but not quite full.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying things to me, so there is no risk of having full storage memory if I keep using ubuntu and installing software?

Comment: You’ve got a long way to go before you run out of disk space, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much